# Issue with if loop in vba to compare first word from two text strings

Tags: vba

the code below is part of a larger Macro, all variables have been specified earlier on but this is the part i'm having the problem with. it's basically meant to loop through a column of company Names and for each company, add up all charges to that company listed on another workbook (essentially like a cost summary for each). Everything seems to work fine except the two rows with ** next to them, here im getting the "Invalid Procedure Call or argument" error and im not sure why. This particular section is meant to compare only the first word in a company name on each workbook (this means different branches are also summed up for a head office total, e.g. so "Company x Group" would include "Company x Manchester" and "Company x London" in its total).

I've tested the two problematic lines in a smaller test macro to see if it actually does represent the first word of the string and it works fine but when i try to use it in this larger macro this is the part that stops it working.

I'm very new to VBA so i understand if the code is a bit clunky and messy but any help would be greatly appreciated. Also apologies for the long winded explanation.

Thanks in Advance!

(the "If Not" part is so only companies that have had sales in this particular week but do not have an amount next to it are taken through the extra loop i.e. "number of sales" isn't empty but "money made" is 0)

```
Dim AgeName As Range
Dim AgeNameB As Range
Dim AgeNameAdd As String
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Double
Dim PostingRange As Range
Dim Postingaddress As String
Dim MarginValueBook As String
Dim MarginValueSheet As String
Dim WENum As String
Dim Postinglocation As Range
Dim L As Integer
Dim M As Double
Dim FirstNameAgeA As String
Dim FirstNameAgeB As String
Dim WENumb As String
Dim AgeComparison As String
Dim FirstWordArrA As String
Dim FirstWordArrB As String

MarginValueBook = "W.E. " & Format(dtTestDate, "DD.MM") & ".csv"
MarginValueSheet = "W.E. " & Format(dtTestDate, "DD.MM")

    For i = 2 To y
        K = 0

        Workbooks("Average Margin Data.xlsm").Activate
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown")

        Set AgeName = ws.Range(celladdress).Offset(i)
        AgeNameAdd = AgeName.Address
        Set PostingRange = Range(AgeNameAdd).Offset(0, 3)
        Postingaddress = PostingRange.Address

        Workbooks(MarginValueBook).Activate
        Set ws = Worksheets(MarginValueSheet)

        Lrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

            For J = 2 To Lrow

                WENum = "A" & J

                If ws.Range(WENum) = UCase(AgeName) Then

                    K = K + ws.Range(WENum).Offset(0, 4).Value

                End If

            Next J

        Set Postinglocation = Range(Postingaddress).Resize(1, 1)
        Postinglocation.Value = K

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown")

            If Not ws.Range(AgeNameAdd).Offset(0, 2) = "" Then

                If ws.Range(AgeNameAdd).Offset(0, 3) = 0 Then

                   For L = 2 To Lrow

                        Set AgeName = ws.Range(celladdress).Offset(i)
                        FirstWordArrA = AgeName.Value
                        'FirstNameAgeA = Trim$(Left$(FirstWordArrA, InStr(FirstWordArrA, " ") - 1))
                        AgeComparison = UCase(FirstNameAgeA)

                        Set wb = Workbooks(MarginValueBook)
                        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(MarginValueSheet)

                        WENumb = "A" & L
                        Set AgeNameB = ws.Range(WENumb)
                        FirstWordArrB = AgeNameB.Value
                        'FirstNameAgeB = Trim$(Left$(FirstWordArrB, InStr(FirstWordArrB, " ") - 1))

                           If AgeComparison = FirstNameAgeB Then

                                M = M + ws.Range(WENumb).Offset(0, 4).Value

                           End If

                    Next L

                    Set Postinglocation = Range(Postingaddress).Resize(1, 1)
                    Postinglocation.Value = M
                    M = 0

                End If


           End If



  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, error marked as comments not with **

Answer (score 0):

Look at the InStr values. Someone might be null. Try to put a onError statement in order to return the correct value.

Comment: I've commented out the two error prone lines and used msgbox to see if the string functions actually contain strings of a positive length and they all do, still not working though

Comment: It seems that sometimes you obtain a 0 for InStr(FirstWordArrA, " ") and when you substract 1, Left$ returns an invalid argument error. Please, split this line in trhee lines and debug them: Trim$(Left$(FirstWordArrA, InStr(FirstWordArrA, " ") - 1))